# Polydactyly and its genetics

Tags: human-genetics

One of my friend was saying that her aunt (father's sibling sister) was having polydactyly but none of her cousins (her aunt has two daughters) is having it.

**What is the chance that my friend's children inherit polydactyly?**

(considering that her partner nor anyone in his generation exhibit polydactyly)

Comment: if polydactyly is autosomal dominant ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydactyly)), then effectively zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polydactyly can be dominant or recessive. that is

1. A single copy of the mutation/s involved result in the phenotype 
   vs
2. Both copies of the gene must be mutated to result in the phenotype

When **two random people** who don't have polydactyly nor a family history of polydactyly have a child, there is around **1/548** (0.18%) chance that child will be **polydactyly** because the parents were carriers without knowing it, and a **1/11.7** (8.54%) chance the child is a **carrier** of a single copy

If the aunt's polydactyly is **Dominant**, then your friend's **father** hasn't inherited it (he isnt polydactyly) and just has the normal population chance of being a carrier.

**In the case of Dominant polydactyly, assuming your friend has a partner with no history of polydactyly, your friend and her partner have the same chance as average of a polydactyly child (1/548)**

If the aunt's polydactyly is **recessive**, meaning she has two copies one from each parent (you friend's grandparents), **there is a 1/130 (0.76%)chance your friend's child will have polydactyly (4.2 times more likely), and a 1/4.5 (21.4%) chance of being a carrier (2.6 times more likely)**

I'll quickly go through the working/ 
if you're interested:

Given that the grandparents are both carriers (needed for the aunt to have two copies), then your friend's **father has a 2/3** chance of being a carrier of a single copy (1/3 chance no copies, 0/3 chance having two copies because he isn't polydactyly).

Your friend's mother has the usual 1/11.7 chance of being a carrier.

The chance of your friend inheriting a single copy is (chance passes from father) + (chance passes from mother) - (chance of getting two copies)

=0.6600/2 + 0.0854/2 - (0.33*0.0427)

=0.3727 - 0.0140

= 0.3586

### 35.9% chance your friend carries one copy

Your friend has 1/2.8 chance of carrying and 1/5.6 of passing it on

### Friend's partner has the 1/11.7 chance of being a carrier and the 1/23.4 chance of passing it on

Therefore their child has

=0.1793*0.0427 (chance friend passes on * chance partner passes on)

=0.0076

=1/130 chance of having two copies, having polydactyly

---

=0.1793 + 0.0427 -(0.1793*0.0427) (chance any copies - chance two copies)

=0.2143

=1/4.7 chance of one copy a 2.5 times increase risk

Comment: That's a really detailed answer. Good one and thanks for simplifying the confusing parts. But can you add any reference? It will help me accept your answer.